# Joomla template module using template images?

Tags: php, templates, joomla1.5

Okay, so I've created a custom template for Joomla, and gotten that working. However, I'm wanting to create a custom option for displaying modules within the template. I found that if I create the appropriate function in the `/html/modules.php` file in my template I can make a

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu" style="myCustom" />
```

call in the template to show modules using that chrome.

That works fine, however I run into the problem that the chrome function wants to use some images from the template itself. In the template `index.php` file I have been accessing images in the template folder by

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/images/logo.png" alt="My Logo" />
```

but the `$this` object doesn't seem to work in the `modules.php` file. How can I get access to the `$this` object that the template was using (I think that's the current View object, but not sure), such that I can get those parameters? Or how best should I refer to an image in the templates directory without hard-coding it with the folder structure my site has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do in your chrome function something like this:
`<img src="<?php echo JURI::base(); ?>/templates/<?php echo JFactory::getApplication()->getTemplate(); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="My Logo" />`

#### Update

@Ahmad Alfy

For the question in your comment, try this in your module:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
echo $doc->direction;
```

Comment: I was trying to access $this->direction in a module file, any tip how to do it? Thanks